# Since + past perfect continuous

Tags: grammaticality, perfect-constructions

I have read some examples in different dictionaries with the word "since". They all give the examples in either the present perfect or the present perfect continuous. I am going to make up an example in the **past** perfect continuous.

> Since he became a physicist twenty years ago, he **had been** doing research on the molecular theories for fifteen years. However, he decided to abandon his physics career for personal reasons.

Is it grammatically correct to use the past perfect continuous in my example?

Answer (score -2):

I think that in that specific context, it makes more sense to say: Since he became a physicist twenty years ago, he **has been** doing research on the molecular theories for fifteen years. However, he decided to abandon his physics career for personal reasons.

Comment: The shift in perspective from the present perfect in the first sentence to the past in the second is at best awkward. At worst it's inconsistent and confusing.